# How to convert list of dictionaries from CSV to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have list of dictionaries from CSV with header test as follows:

```
[{'points': 50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010}, 
{'points': 25, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"}, 
{'points':90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'}, 
{'points_h1':20, 'month': 'june'}]
```

when I use pd.DataFrame[Dataset["test"]], the output is the same, which is :

```
[{'points': 50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010}, 
{'points': 25, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"}, 
{'points':90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'}, 
{'points_h1':20, 'month': 'june'}]
```

How do I explode this dictionary?

Edit:  It only works when I copy and paste the output manually as a new variable and then pd.dataframe it again.

```
a = [{'points': 50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010}, 
{'points': 25, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"}, 
{'points':90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'}, 
{'points_h1':20, 'month': 'june'}]
```

Then the dataframe table appears.

I'm sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: What do you mean with `output`? The data can be loaded without any issues with `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: This time, it doesn't load, surprisingly. It only works when I copy and paste the output as a new variable and then pd.dataframe it again. Is there anyway to convert it?

Comment: what is the name of column in which these list of dictionary is stored?

Comment: the column name is "keywords". The list of dictionaries is in the CSV file

Comment: can you please post the output of `df.head()` so that we know how your dataframe looks like?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code failed is that your input file is actually **not**
any CSV file. It is a **string representation** of your list of
dictionaries (not a list of dictionaries).

I assume that your input file contains what you put as the first sample.

To handle such an input file properly, you can:

- **read** the whole file into a variable (which will be of *str* type),
- **evaluate** it to create an actual **list**, but for security
  reasons it is advisable to use *ast.literal_eval*,
- only then create your DataFrame from this list.

The code to do it is:

```
import ast
with open('Input.txt') as reader:
    txt = reader.read()
lst = ast.literal_eval(txt)
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

The result is:

```
   points  time    year     month  points_h1
0    50.0  5:00  2010.0       NaN        NaN
1    25.0  6:00     NaN  february        NaN
2    90.0  9:00     NaN   january        NaN
3     NaN   NaN     NaN      june       20.0
```

## Another approach

Or maybe your input file is a CSV file anyway, something like:

```
{'points': 50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010};x1
{'points': 25, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"};x2
{'points':90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'};x3
{'points_h1':20, 'month': 'june'};x4
```

I put above actual CSV content, with 2 columns with no names.
In order not to break the first colum into several columns, I assumed
that the column separator is some **other** char than a comma, e.g.
a semicolon.

You can read such file as:

```
Dataset = pd.read_csv('Input.txt', sep=';', names=['test', 'test2'])
```

Then, to create your DataFrame from *test* column of *Dataset*
(actually a source DataFrame), apply the following function to each
element of *Dataset.test*:

```
df = Dataset.test.apply(lambda tt: pd.Series(ast.literal_eval(tt)))
```

The result is just the same as above.

Comment: Is it possible to do this to a dataframe? because the csv file has many columns, and I will combine multiple csv into df.

Comment: *Dataset* is a DataFrame and *df* is also a DataFrame. Maybe you should ask another question, with more details about your source and expected result.